# jQuery slider redirect the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slider, slideshow

I'm using [jQuery Blinds Slideshow](http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/blinds/) as image slider. I want to redirect the first sliding image to http://google.com when I click on it. I use `a` html tag like this:

```
<div class="slideshow">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="http://google.com"><img src="lemons/1.jpg" alt="lemon" /></a></li>
      <li><img src="lemons/2.jpg" alt="lemon tea" /></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<a href="#" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(0)">1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(1)">2</a>
```

but it doesn't work.
My question is how can I redirect the first sliding image to google.com  when I click on it ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something quick and dirty I cooked up modifying the original jquery-blinds. 
Put it in a new JS file and call it jquery.blinds-0.9-with-hyperlinks.js or something and include it in place of the current jquery-blinds code.

It should work with the HTML you posted above. It simply checks if any of the images are wrapped in an '' tag and if it is, makes the image redirect to that link on click.

```js
/*!
 * jQuery Blinds
 * http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/blinds
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Vassilis Dourdounis
 * 
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 * 
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 * 
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 * Modified by Thomas Antony ( http://www.thomasantony.net ) on 06-Apr-2012
 * Added image hyperlinking functionality
 *
 */
(function($){

    $.fn.blinds = function (options) {

        $(this).find('li').hide();
        $(this).addClass('blinds_slideshow');

        settings = {};
        settings.tile_orchestration = this.tile_orchestration;

        settings.h_res = 12;
        settings.v_res = 1;

        settings.width = $(this).find('li:first').width();
        settings.height = $(this).find('li:first').height();

        jQuery.extend(settings, options);

        tiles_width = settings.width / settings.h_res;
        tiles_height = settings.height / settings.v_res;

        // Get image list
        blinds_images = [];
        blinds_links = [];

        $(this).find('img').each(function (i, e) {
            blinds_images[blinds_images.length] = {'title': e.alt, 'src': e.src}
            // Code added to allow for linking functionality -- Thomas
            if( $(e).parent().is('a') && $(e).parent().attr('href') != undefined)
            {
                blinds_links[i] = $(e).parent().attr('href');
            }else{
                blinds_links[i] = "";
            }
        });

        // Create blinds_container
        $(this).append('<div class="blinds_container"></div>');

        blinds_container = $(this).find('.blinds_container');
        blinds_container.css({
            'position'  : 'relative', 
            'display'   : 'block', 
            'width'     : settings.width, 
            'height'    : settings.height, 
//          'border'    : '1px solid red', // debuging
            'background': 'transparent url("' + blinds_images[1]['src'] + '") 0px 0px no-repeat'
        } );


        // Setup tiles
        for (i = 0; i < settings.h_res; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < settings.v_res; j++)
            {
                if (tile = $(this).find('.tile_' + i + '_' + j))
                {
                    h = '<div class="outer_tile_' + i + '_' + j + '"><div class="tile_' + i + '_' + j + '"></div></div>';
                    blinds_container.append(h);
                    outer_tile = $(this).find('.outer_tile_' + i + '_' + j);
                    outer_tile.css({
                        'position'  : 'absolute',
                        'width'     : tiles_width,
                        'height'    : tiles_height,
                        'left'      : i * tiles_width,
                        'top'       : j * tiles_height
                    })

                    tile = $(this).find('.tile_' + i + '_' + j);
                    tile.css({
                        'position'  : 'absolute',
                        'width'     : tiles_width,
                        'height'    : tiles_height,
                        'left'      : 0,
                        'top'       : 0,
//                      'border'    : '1px solid red', // debuging
                        'background': 'transparent url("' + blinds_images[0]['src'] + '") -' + (i * tiles_width) + 'px -' + (j * tiles_height) + 'px no-repeat' 
                    })

                    jQuery.data($(tile)[0], 'blinds_position', {'i': i, 'j': j});
                }
            }
        }

        jQuery.data(this[0], 'blinds_config', {
            'h_res': settings.h_res,
            'v_res': settings.v_res,
            'tiles_width': tiles_width,
            'tiles_height': tiles_height,
            'images': blinds_images,
            'img_index': 0,
            'change_buffer': 0,
            'tile_orchestration': settings.tile_orchestration
        });


        // Add redirection code for the links -- Thomas 
        var container = this[0];    // Need this to get config data within click handler
        jQuery.data(this[0], 'blinds_links', blinds_links);

        blinds_container.click(function(){
            var config = jQuery.data(container, 'blinds_config');
            if(blinds_links[config.img_index] != "")
            {
                window.location.href = blinds_links[config.img_index]
            }
        }); 
        $(this).update_cursor(); // Set correct cursor for first image -- Thomas
        // Modified code ends

    }

    $.fn.blinds_change = function (img_index) {

        // reset all sprites
        config = jQuery.data($(this)[0], 'blinds_config');
        for (i = 0; i < config.h_res; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < config.v_res; j++) {
                $(this).find('.tile_' + i + '_' + j).show().css('background', 'transparent ' + 'url("' + config.images[config.img_index]['src'] + '") -' + (i * config.tiles_width) + 'px -' + (j * config.tiles_height) + 'px no-repeat');
            }
        }

        $(this).children('.blinds_container').css('background', 'transparent url("' + blinds_images[img_index]['src'] + '") 0px 0px no-repeat' );

        config.img_index = img_index;
        jQuery.data($(this)[0], 'blinds_config', config);

        for (i = 0; i < config.h_res; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < config.v_res; j++) {
                t = config.tile_orchestration(i, j, config.h_res, config.v_res);

                config = jQuery.data($(this)[0], 'blinds_config');
                config.change_buffer = config.change_buffer + 1;
                jQuery.data(this[0], 'blinds_config', config);

                $(this).find('.tile_' + i + '_' + j).fadeOut(t, function() {
                    blinds_pos = jQuery.data($(this)[0], 'blinds_position');
                    config = jQuery.data($(this).parents('.blinds_slideshow')[0], 'blinds_config');

                    $(this).css('background', 'transparent ' + 'url("' + config.images[config.img_index]['src'] + '") -' + (blinds_pos.i * config.tiles_width) + 'px -' + (blinds_pos.j * config.tiles_height) + 'px no-repeat');

                    config.change_buffer = config.change_buffer - 1;
                    jQuery.data($(this).parents('.blinds_slideshow')[0], 'blinds_config', config);

                    if (config.change_buffer == 0) {
//                      $(this).parent().parent().children().children().css('width', config.tiles_width);
                        $(this).parent().parent().children().children().show();
                    }

                });
            }
        }
        $(this).update_cursor();
    }

    $.fn.tile_orchestration = function (i, j, total_x, total_y) {
        return (Math.abs(i-total_x/2)+Math.abs(j-total_y/2))*100;
    }

    // Function to update cursor to a "hand" if image is linked -- Thomas
    $.fn.update_cursor = function()
    {
        // Change cursor if image is hyperlinked
        var config = jQuery.data($(this)[0], 'blinds_config');
        var blinds_links = jQuery.data($(this)[0], 'blinds_links'); // get links from saved data

        console.log(config.img_index);
        if(blinds_links[config.img_index] != "")
        {
            $(this).find('.blinds_container').css('cursor','pointer');
        }else{
            $(this).find('.blinds_container').css('cursor','auto');
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a:first').click(function(){
        window.location.href = 'http://google.com/';
    });
});
</script>
```

Or

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.slideshow img:first').click(function(){
        window.location.href = 'http://google.com/';
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry but these don't work for this plugin. when I try your code for the image which is not in slider, it does work, but when I try this code for the image which is in slider, it doesn't work :( could you download this plugin and try it, please ?

Comment: you haven't included js function which is enabling slider  $(window).load(function () {
  // start the slideshow
  $('.slideshow').blinds();
 })